# Hide/Show DIV upon drilldown in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to be able to hide/show a relevant `DIV` when drilling down on a Highcharts pie chart.

For example, I have 5 pieces of my pie, and 6 DIVs.

I want to show DIV 6 (called `DIVGENERAL`) when its not drilled down, but then the section specific DIV when drilled down on a section.

For example if I drill down on `Account 1`, I want to hide `DIV 6` and display `DIV 1`, If I drill down on `Account 4`, I want to hide `DIV 6` and display `DIV 4`

I have been able to get it to successfully **hide** `DIV 6` when drilling down, and to **show**  it when you drill back up.

If I specify a `DIV` in the drill down function it will hide it, but I need to be able to tell it which `DIV` to hide based on which section of the pie has been drilled down on.

I have created a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AntonZdz/gqu1u940/) that shows where I am to date.

```
events: {
    drilldown: function (e) {
        alert('Drill Down');
        document.getElementById('Account 1').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('AccountGeneral').style.display = "none";
    },
    drillup: function (e) {
        alert('Drill Up');
        document.getElementById('Account 1').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('AccountGeneral').style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at updated fiddle code:

http://jsfiddle.net/gqu1u940/5/

I have added an JS object for mapping chart section to its panel like:

```
var panelMapping = {
    "Account 1": "Panel1",
    "Account 2": "Panel2",
    "Account 3": "Panel3",
    "Account 4": "Panel4",
    "Account 5": "Panel5"
  }
```

and in `drilldown:` event handler we can get which section got drilled down as:

```
drilldown: function(e) {
    alert('Drill Down : ' + e.point.name);
    var associatedPanelId = panelMapping[e.point.name];
    document.getElementById(associatedPanelId).style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('Panel6').style.display = "none";
},
drillup: function(e) {
    alert('Drill Up');
    var panels = document.getElementsByClassName("Panel");
    for (var i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
        panels[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    document.getElementById('Panel6').style.display = "block";
}
```

**Note:** I have added a class `Panel` to all the panel from `Panel1` to `Panel5` which i am using while hiding all the panel while `drillup` event

Comment: This is perfect, and exactly what I was trying to achieve. Thanks!

Comment: had a fun while doing this. Thanks @AntonZ...`:)`!